# Entire function with zeros only at the natural numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, entire-functions

It follows from Weierstrass theorem that there exists an entire function with zeros only at prescribed points.

But let's say we have a particular sequence of prescribed points, for example $\{a_n\} = \mathbb{N}$.

> **How do we built the entire function with zeros only at those points**
>   **constructively?**

Comment: You can choose $\exp (2\pi z) - 1$; this also has the negative integers as zeros.

Comment: @AhmedHussein My bad, I meant "with zeros *only* at prescribed points"

Comment: maybe try $f(z)=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-\frac{z}{n})$ and hope it converges and is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem).

Comment: The proof of the Weierstrass theorem is constructive, so if you want to know what to do with a general sequence you should probably just learn it. If you're interested in finding an elegant-looking function for your specific sequence, that's another story. Something along the lines of $\frac{1}{\Gamma(-z)}$ will probably do the trick...